# Ant Design date picker disable array of dates

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datepicker, ant-design-pro

I need to disable date before today (did it with disabledDate function). And I need to disable specific dates on calendar, like:

Today: 10/17/2022

Dates need to disable:

```
const dates = [
  "10/22/2022",
  "10/23/2022",
  "10/29/2022",
  "10/30/2022",
  "11/05/2022",
  "11/06/2022",
  "11/12/2022",
  "11/13/2022",
  "11/19/2022",
  "11/20/2022",
  "11/26/2022",
  "11/27/2022",
  "12/03/2022",
  "12/04/2022",
  "12/10/2022",
  "12/11/2022",
  "12/17/2022",
  "12/18/2022",
  "10/17/2022",
  "10/18/2022",
  "10/19/2022",
  "10/20/2022",
  "10/21/2022"
];
```

I've made a function like this it's still wrong

```
function disabledDate(current: any) {
for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  if(current.date() === moment(dates[i]).date() && current.month() === moment(dates[i]).month()){
    return false;
  }     
}
return true;  }
```

I want something like displayed in below image
[image]

Thanks!